# Order in which JavaScript reads code

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering in what order does JavaScript executes code. From what I understand, Javascript doesn't go from top to bottom. I would just like to know what it reads first and why.

Also, I have been experimenting with js and noticed that if I write a function:

```
$('#closeMenu').click(function() {
    $('#menu').hide();
});
```

It will run at anytime. So, am I right to conclude that if I write a function to open a menu outside of a function, anytime the user clicks on the button to open a menu, the menu will open? Does js re-use blocks of codes if the event is called by the user?

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Javascript is executed from top to bottom, why do you think otherwise? Event handlers are registered with the browser, and they get run asynchronously whenever the associated event occurs.

Comment: Just so we are on the same page - it's `jQuery` code (not plain JS).

Comment: Here you go https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you've created an event listener. Any time a user clicks on the specified DOM element, the event will fire and trigger the callback you've passed to the click() function.

Event listeners are read into memory when the code is read, but the inner function is only executed when the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Code in javascript is read from top to bottom. Whichever code is seen first is executed first.

Yes you can write code to open menu like

```
$('#closeMenu').click(function() {
    $('#menu').show();
});
```

This is because these are event listeners and they don't execute unless the event they are listening for happens